# Performance considerations for SUB QUERY, LIMIT and ORDER BY when using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery, sql-limit

Objective: Select 10 users whose ongoing games is < 5.

**Approach 1: Do everything within MySQL**

Select users (LIMIT 10) and check n_ongoingGames for each user

**Approach 2: SQL + result-set analysis**

Get records for say 30 users.
For each record, go to db again and check for n_ongoingGames. Assuming probability of (n_ongoingGames > 5) for each user as 50%, we'll need to check for 20 records.

```
-- Approach 1: Do everything within MySQL
-- --------------------------------------
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u
WHERE 
    ( -- n_ongoingGames for user < 5
        (
            SELECT COUNT(gameID) AS n_ongoingGames
            FROM games g
            WHERE 
                (g.player1_userID = u.userID) OR 
                (g.player2_userID = u.userID) OR
                (g.player3_userID = u.userID) OR
                ...
                ...
                ...
                (g.player10_userID = u.userID)
        ) < 5
    ) AND
    (u.cash_balance > 500)
ORDER BY u.user_rating
LIMIT 10;


-- Approach 2: SQL + result-set analysis
-- -------------------------------------
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u
WHERE
    (u.cash_balance > 500)
ORDER BY u.user_rating
LIMIT 30;
```

Questions:

1. In approach 1, does MySQL check (n_ongoingGames for user < 5) for every user in the users table ?
2. Which approach is faster ?
3. Does it make a difference (on which approach is faster) if only 1 user is needed instead of 10 (LIMIT 1)

Thanks.

Comment: why do you limit to 10 the first query?

Comment: Let's say, this application facilitates group discussion for 10 users. And each user can at best be part of 5 ongoing discussions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what's a group discussion, put in perspective with your model description. Also, this does not comply with the initial requirement `Select users whose ongoing games is < 5.`, which does not mention any user limit. I'm convinced this limit is not relevant, from the sql query perspective. If there's a quantity constraint on the number of rows, they should be ensured by the application or by actual database constraints.

Comment: 10 users are given a topic to discuss/debate. A user can participate in multiple debates/discussions simultaneously. But n_simultaneous_debates < 5. You're right - I modified the objective statement accordingly and added 10 to it.

Comment: ok, let me review that

Comment: Holy crap, 10 user fields? If you're really concerned about performance, please normalize all that ASAP

Comment: Yup, duly noted. I wanted to keep the question simple with only 2 tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following, assuming a user cannot be both players:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM USERS u
WHERE u.cash_balance > 500 AND
      ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS n_ongoingGames
        FROM games g
        WHERE g.player1_userID = u.userID
       ) +
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n_ongoingGames
        FROM games g
        WHERE g.player2_userID = u.userID
       )
      ) < 5
ORDER BY u.user_rating
LIMIT 10;
```

With the following indexes:  `games(player1_userID)` and `games(player2_userID)`.  You also want an index on users; one possibility is `users(user_rating, cash_balance)`, but I don't think MySQL will be smart enough to scan the table in order using the index.  You might have to settle for `users(cash_balance)`.

The indexes on `games()` mean that the counts can be satisfied in the indexes.  This should be a particularly fast type of counting.  If you remove the condition on cash balance, then an index on `users(user_rating)` should make the query quite fast.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear earlier. A game consists of 10 users. For a new game, we want to select 10 users, and we're checking among existing games whether the (n_ongoingGames < 5). The potential user may be playing as player1, player2 ... player10 in any of the existing games.